# Can USB-C charging be universal across devices? Compatibility does not seem to work. Would the issue be with USB-C cable or USB-C wall power adapter?

Tags: usb-c, power

I have these devices that use USB-C to charge:

- [Xiberia G01 Gaming Headphones](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08J82VNSW)
- [Bose QC 45 noise cancelling headphones](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B098FKXT8L)
- [Momcozy white noise machine](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B099RSXLGH)

This is the wall power adapter I am trying to use to charge the headphones and the baby sound machine via a USB-C to USB-C cable, but it does not work.

My question is:

#### What wall power adapter can I use instead of the KOOPAO adapter to charge all items via USB-C to USB-C?

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B099W69QL6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B099W69QL6)

[image: USB-A and USB-C power adapter]

The headphones and sound machine only charge if I use a USB-A (for the wall outlet) to USB-C cable (pictured below).

I just bought brand new Anker cables, so I know they cannot all be defective.

[image: USB-A and USB-C cable]

Comment: Hi SamAndrew81, unfortunately we don't handle debugging requests here on the Hardware Recs StackExchange; I'm going to migrate this to Superuser, you may get more help there. I would normally guess some sort of USB-PD negotiation issue, but since they all seem to be working fine with 5V, I kinda doubt that. In any case, it's real tough to say without getting more hands-on debugging info via something like a USB power meter.

Comment: @JMY1000, please don't transfer to to SuperUser. I asked there first and they closed it. Where or where can I ask this question? No one wants to help :(

Comment: @SamAndrew81 Sorry to hear that, I'm not entirely sure why this question is off-topic on Superuser; it looks like just because the question is too specific? Not sure I understand that. Unfortunately in any case, debugging existing devices really is quite outside the scope of this site; we focus on providing recommendations for new hardware, not fixing existing hardware.

Comment: If you're looking for a recommendation on a new charging brick to replace your KOOPAO, that's something we could help with. If that's the case, go ahead and edit your post to reflect that, and I can reopen your question (and hopefully provide an answer.) If you're just interested in debugging your existing charger/devices, your best bet might be getting a USB-C power meter, doing a little debugging, and trying to post again on Superuser or the Electronics StackExchange with more info.

Comment: It's not the charger's fault, your devices have a noncompliant USB C port: it needs two resistors so when a compliant source is connected the device can be recognized as a sink even if it doesn't have a PD controller. This is a very common mistake alas either because of utter ignorance (manufacturer doesn't know anything about USB C standard and just changes the micro USB socket to a USB C socket) or utter stupidity (I read some manufacturers claim if they let C-C chargers work with their device then they might be damaged). Return them, rate them with 1* and tell the manufacturer to fix them.

Comment: If you so want, you can use any USB C charger with a C male to micro USB male cable and a micro USB female to USB C male adapter. This creates a C-C cable which is 5V hot. It's not ideal, by far, but it does work. Do note I specified what is male and what is female, the other way around is _not_ specifications compliant even if dubious sellers on Amazon and such sell them: the specification explicitly forbids C receptacle to legacy USB adapters.

Comment: Finally, toss or return that charger and buy something that has both AC side (UL / ETL / TUV) and DC side (USB IF) certification. How do people land on these random garbage chargers, I can't fathom.

Comment: @SamAndrew81 Not a full answer since it seems like all your devices only require a basic 5V/1A charger, but I'd give [this UGREEN 35W USB C charger](https://www.amazon.com/UGREEN-Charger-2-Ports-Foldable-Compact/dp/B0CFFCHQDT/) a shot; in my experience, UGREEN is quite reliable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I don’t think USB-C charging can be universal across devices.

#### This is not a charger or cable issue, but the manufacturers of basic consumer products do not set their devices with proper power negotiation circuits. Not much can be done in cases like that.

I think the issue is the basic consumer products you are attempting to charge can only charge a 5 volts at 1 amp (5W) and cannot negotiate with a higher wattages wall charger.

I say this without having solid specs on this, but I personally have converted to all USB-C items on my MacBook Air and have some items that can technically charge via USB-C but only do so when I connect them to a 5W USB-A charger. Items like a no-name “Aidisun” [bike flashlight](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09JBMH2NG) and such.

Look at what your KOOPAO (!?!) can charge at:

##### USB-C PD (Power Delivery)

- **5V/3A**: 15W
- **9V/2.25A**: 20.25W
- **12V/1.67A**: 20.04W

##### USB-A QC 3.0 (Quick Charge 3.0)

- **5V/3A**: 15W
- **9V/2.25A**: 20.25W
- **12V/1.5A**: 18W

Nowhere does it say “5V/1A” but somehow that comes through with the USB-A connection?

It baffles me, but my bet would be that all of the consumer products you mention:

- Xiberia G01 Gaming Headphones
- Bose QC 45 noise cancelling headphones
- Momcozy white noise machine

While they might have a USB-C connection, they can only work with USB-A connections because the manufacturers somehow did not set their devices with proper power negotiation circuits? They are effectively “dumb” USB devices that can only take what they are given but only if not above a certain (5 volts at 1 amp) wattage?

I wouldn’t waste time with new cables or even a new charger. Sorry to say, I don’t believe the promise of USB-C charging across devices exists. Especially when makers of USB-C chargers and devices that claim to be cable of USB-C charging are so opaque about power requirements.

---

FWIW, I just tried this out but if I connect a USB-A (Male) to USB-C (Male) to a USB-A (Female) to USB-C (Male) adapter I can successfully charge by crappy “Aidisun” bike flashlight. According to my USB-C power meter, power is sent at 2.5W (5V/0.5A) which is pretty low.

So I wonder if this the case where some consumer devices that have USB-C power adapters charge at 2.5W (5V/0.5A) but somehow can’t negotiate with higher wattage AC adapters? Like if it is less than 5W (5V/1A) on pure USB-C to USB-C it doesn’t know what to do?

My guess is your USB-C to USB-C charging problems won’t go away with a new AC adapter because the problem is ultimately with the consumer devices themselves.

Comment: USB-PD negotiation failures would make sense for anything other than the standard 5V charging; however, I'm like 98% sure that the USB-C spec specifies that 5V output is sent by default, and doesn't require and USB-PD negotiation. It's possible that the KOOPAO charger isn't following spec—that's pretty common, especially for a brand that's not really well known—but the 5V delivery is about as basic as it gets, so that should really work even if there are USB-PD issues.

Comment: It looks like it was bought through Amazon, so a return to Amazon would probably be easier and faster lol.